# What is the proper way to the pattern form Repeated in my code?

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm matching a pattern with `Repeated (..)` How can I use the repeat count in the replacement rule?

Example:

```
 Cases[ { {0, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} ,
     {0, Repeated[x_ /; x != 5], 5, __} :> {0, Sequence @@ Table[x, {2}], 5}]
                                                                     ^ <---?
```

> {{0, 2, 2, 5}}

Obviously instead of hard coding the `2` I want the length of the repeat..

My workaround for this example is this:

```
 #[[;; First@First@Position[#, 5]]] & /@
     Cases[ { {0, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2}, {0, 5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} ,
       {0, Repeated[x_ /; x != 5], 5, __} ]
```

> {{0, 2, 2, 5}}

It seems there should be a cleaner solution though.

Comment: Use named patterns: `Cases[{{0, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {0, rep : Repeated[x_ /; x != 5], 5, __} :> {0, rep, 5}]`.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe this should be closed if you think it too simple.

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion here. It may be simple for those who used this many times, but I bet many people might have such questions. And, the fact that a 5K rep user bothered to ask it may mean that it is not trivial at the very least. Let's wait what others think.

Comment: On second thought, I actually think we should keep this one - it is a nice example of more complex patterns, where one really does need two pattern variables, one for the entire pattern and another one to restrict its parts.

Answer (score 4):

Just so this doesn't sit unanswered, per @LeonidShifrin comment:

```
 Cases[{{0, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
     {0, rep : Repeated[x_ /; x != 5], 5, __} :> {0, rep, 5}]
```

or : `{0, rep :  x_ .. /; x != 5  , 5, __}`

For completeness if you literally wanted to use the form in the question:

```
 Cases[{{0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
         {0,rep : Repeated[x_ /; x != 5], 5, __} :>
         {0,Sequence @@ Table[ x, {Length@List@rep}], 5}]
```

Comment: so as not to give readers the impression that `Repeated` picks out the sub-expression `,2,2, ` because it contains repeated two's, it might be useful to generalise to: `Cases[{{0,2,2,5,2,4,1,2},{0,1,2,3,4,5}},{0,pat: x_ ..,y_,__}:>{0,pat,y}/;Length[{pat}]>1]` or, in alternative form: `Cases[{{0, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {0, rep : Repeated[x_ /; x != 5, {2, \[Infinity]}], 
   y_, __} :> {0, rep, y} ]`

Comment: for my application I intended the basic "one or more" meaning of `Repeated`